# How many messages have passed through Azure Service Bus during the last minute?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I want to programmatically know how many messages were posted/retrieved from the queue during the last minute. Azure portal allows viewing this:
[image]

I want to get the same data in my application for further analysis. It would be better to have this info for the last day but knowing value just from now on will also work. I know how to get the current count of messages from the `MessageCountDetails` class, but this is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to programmatically know how many messages were posted/retrieved from the queue during the last minute. Azure portal allows viewing this

You can do that using [Monitor Service API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/).
The new .NETSTD client doesn't provide an equivalent to the .NETFX `MessageCountDetails`, so I've put together a [sample](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/reading-azure-service-bus-metrics) how to retrieve metrics using Monitor Service API you could use as a starting point.

Comment: Your post mentions `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor` DLL. Where can I find it? I do not see it on the nuget.org.

Comment: It's a preview assembly, requires opt-in.

Comment: Thanks! When it will be in release? (Approx)

Comment: Unfortunately, don't have that info.

Comment: I managed to get data using this API. I do not see any "MessageCount" metrics there. How can I query data for individual message queues? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that's next to be added. You might want to ping on GitHub to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

Until Monitor Service API is released, you could use [Service Bus Entity Metrics REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/service-bus-entity-metrics-rest-apis). You won't get per-second count - the minimal resolution is 5 minutes, but you can get some values from the past, not just the last interval. Also note that there is some lag before the value is available there (minutes).

[Azure Service Bus Entity Metrics .NET APIs](https://mikhail.io/2017/03/azure-service-bus-entity-metrics-dotnet-apis/) shows how to get these metrics from C#.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-azure-monitor) provides monitoring of resources based on metrics, logs, etc. Using [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent) library, metrics for the resources mentioned here can be retrieved.